# Google Font Cookie does not work in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

On the following site the titles (.post-header) should look like in this picture (Google Font: Cookie). If i analyze it, it seems to take the code but doesnt work. Can you help?

http://www.vintagemaedchen.de

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS file of the font is missing. You have to insert the following line into the `<head>` area:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Cant find the right sheet. Can you help me pls?
Allready tried in stylesheet.css 

This is the list of sheets:

Comment: the line should be insert in the `header.php` file, there should be the `<head>` area.

Comment: In wordpress better use [wp enqueue scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) to load scripts and styles.